80's movie about a journalist investigating the murder of a gang victim
I saw this movie years ago, I think it came out in the 1980's, it's an American movie. It's about a young guy who was chased by a gang and he ran into an old couple's house. 
After fearing what the gang would do to the old couple he threw himself out of the house and was killed by the gang. Most of the movie was about a journalist investigating what happened that night because everyone in the neighborhood thought that the old man had thrown the boy out of the house to get killed but only in the end of the film did she discover that the boy sacrificed himself to save the couple. The old man never told anyone else what happened because he was shamed he didn't protect the boy. At the end of the film when the journalist left the old couples house the gang came to kill her for investigating but the old man decided to stand up to them this time and helped scare them away.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification.What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

This question has plenty of detail.

I've been trying to remember the name of this film for years. The good news is I finally found it! It is called Night of Courage. I always thought it was called Night of Fear, but I was wrong. It's a TV movie from 1987. There are records of it online. The bad news is that there doesn't seem to be a DVD release anywhere on the internet. At least not that I can find.
